# How to manage ajax in nested forms?

Tags: forms, ajax

As implied in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25281/example-of-entity-within-entity-subform-processing), I'm adding a list of similar child forms to my parent form with the following code:

```
foreach ($form_state['items'] as $key => $item) {

    $existing = NULL;
    if (isset($form['item_holder'][$key])) {
        $existing = $form['item_holder'][$key];
    }

    $state = NULL;
    if (isset($form_state['item_holder'][$key])) {
        $state = $form_state['item_holder'][$key];
    }

    $el = item_form_edit($existing, $state, $item);

    $form['item_holder'][$key] = $el;   
}
```

I am calling the form function directly because drupal_get_form() was causing errors due to confusion about which form was being submitted.

My child form type has ajax callbacks that return parts of it $form object. But  the child's callback function is receiving the parent form's object and causing an error trying to return parts of the child form.

How do I sort out ajax calls between parent and child $form contexts? Do I need to go back and add the child forms with drupal_get_form()? If so, how do I avoid confusing which form has been submitted?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a nested form. That is simply impossible, a <form> tag may no contain another <form> tag, that has nothing to do with using drupal_get_form().

Comment: Interesting - I agree that <form> should not contain <form> but my approach below is working great on chrome, firefox, safari and IE.

Comment: For a variety of reasons, I abandoned the manual subform approach and am working with the Subform module. Next steps here >> http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25725/processing-forms-together-for-a-tree-of-related-entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Drupal will distinguish ajax for subforms automatically if you work within the system - which I was not.

Instead of calling the form builder function directly *(bad)*, I use drupal_get_form() so the code above becomes:

```
foreach ($form_state['items'] as $key => $item) {

    $form['item_holder'][$key] = drupal_get_form('item_form_edit', $item);

}
```

I was previously loading the subitem's code with module_load_include(). I now load the sub-item's code with form_load_include() which should make a cached version of this form load correctly.

Since I am building a list of similar subforms, the subform needs to make sure it gets a unique wrapper:

```
function item_form_edit($form, &$form_state, $edit = NULL) {

    $id_string = 'sub-item-form';
    $unique_id = drupal_html_id($id_string);    

    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="' . $unique_id . '">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    ...

    return $form;
}
```

Now, an AJAX element on the subform can replace that subform with

```
    '#ajax' => array(
        'wrapper' => $unique_id,
        'callback' => 'subform_callback',
        ...
```

In this example, the entire subform is being replaced by the callback:

```
function subform_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    return $form;
}
```

My subform builder function is in a separate file, so hook_init() needs to make Drupal aware of the subform code during AJAX requests:

```
if ($_GET['q'] == 'system/ajax' || strstr($_GET['q'], 'file/ajax/')) {
    if (preg_match('/item_form_edit/', $_POST['form_id'])) {
        module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'file_with_item_form');
    }
}
```